# Get length of a function in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, nowjs-sockets

I'm using nodejs and nowjs. I want to get the body length of the function that is calling the function on the server and check if it is the same. To prevent users from manipulating the client side function. And possibly excluding variables that may change. Is there a way to do this in javascript?

eg

client

```
now.sendMessage() {
    //Some code...
}
```

server

```
everyone.now.sendMessage() {
    //Check that the code is the exact length 
    //as the function body written in the clientside script
    //To see if it has been manipulated...
    if (codelength === ?) {
        //execute code
    } else {
       //return error
    }
}
```

Comment: No. what your trying to achieve is not possible.

Comment: Think about, the whole thing is still using HTTP at it's core. It's extremely easy to write a script in a different language and just send "some numbers" at the server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be done: http://jsfiddle.net/RsrCB/1/.

But in practice, it's not reliable. JavaScript code can't be checked for integrity for several reasons:

- It's easy to obfuscate it
- It's easy to override the integrity-checking code

Comment: No, because even in the original version of my answer I expressed that it should not be done.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
   var codelength =  (String(yourfunction_name).length);
```

With that knowledge you can also calculate some hash over the body of the function and compare those.

Answer (score 2):

Your using now wrong. You cannot trust the user.

With now you just define procedures on the client and call them with some data. You do not pass sensitive data like this.

Any data you send to the client belongs to the client, you cannot shield against hijacking.

now uses websockets or XHR underneath. Your simply sending data to a client on a socket, it can be intercepted.

Comment: Im not sure i understand this. what do you mean by sensitive data? If this is only a guestbook record or something? How should i use nowjs then? I posted a new question about this. Thanks

Comment: @George sounded like you were trying to implement some kind of security.